# R package arules: read.transactions file format

Tags: r, arules

I have a .csv file with the following type of data:

```
Day Item
1 12,19,24,31,48,
1 1,19,
1 16,28,32,45,
1 19,36,41,43,44,
1 7,24,27,
1 21,31,33,41,
1 46
1 50
2 12,31,36,48,
2 17,29,47,
2 2,18,20,29,38,39,40,41
2 17,29,47,
```

And I can't get the read.transactions to read it properly.

The data set is based on several item selection for each day (more than one time per day, if necessary). For instance, the third selection on day 1, returned items 16,28,32, and 45.

Shouldn't this be enough?

```
library(arules)
dataset <- read.transactions("file.csv", format = 'basket')
```

Comment: I think you need to specify the `sep`

Comment: What happens when you try the code? An error? What error?

Comment: @akrun, thanks for your comment. However, I already tried to specify `sep=","` or even revome the commas from the CSV but the dataset analysis isn't done properly

Comment: You have a quote missing in `basket`.  If i do `read.transactions("file.csv", format = 'basket', sep=",")#
transactions in sparse format with
 13 transactions (rows) and
 32 items (columns)`

Comment: @IceCreamToucan the dataset isn't analyzed properly. For instance, it is saying that all rows have only 2 elements (it must be using only the first two numbers). Instead, it should be detecting the first as a class and the following (separeted by commas), as the elements.

Comment: Also, tjhe `skip=1` to remove the header

Comment: @akrun that was a typo only here, thanks
However, using `sep=","` makes it assume for instance `1 12` as a label (for first line). And that shouldn't happen. I should only get (for this example) labels `1` and `2`, when using `dataset@itemInfo[["labels"]]`

Comment: Perhaps you can read it with `read.csv` and `split` i.e. `df1 <- read.csv('file.csv', sep=""); as(split(df1$Item, df1$Day), "transactions")`

Comment: The issue is that you have elements as string. You may need to `split` the string

Comment: If you need to split up, `lst1 <- lapply(split(df1$Item, df1$Day), function(x)  lapply(strsplit(x, ","), as.numeric)); dataset <-  lapply(lst1, as, 'transactions'); lapply(dataset, summary)`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to create a sample data using data provided by you

```
data <- read.table(text="Day Item
1 12,19,24,31,48,
1 1,19,
1 16,28,32,45,
1 19,36,41,43,44,
1 7,24,27,
1 21,31,33,41,
1 46
1 50
2 12,31,36,48,
2 17,29,47,
2 2,18,20,29,38,39,40,41
2 17,29,47",header = T)

data <- as(data[-1], "transactions") ##removing 1st header column for the transactional data

inspect(data)

## apply apriori algorithm ###

rules <- apriori(data, parameter = list(supp = 0.001, conf = 0.80))


### Arrange top 10 rules by lift ####

inspect(rules[1:10])
```

Please try this method hope it helps